# Extracting elements from a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am geting the data in this format .

```
{"items":[["Jan 1, 2010",1],["Jan 2, 2010",2]]}
```

Is it possible to store only the dates from the array ?? 
Please help

when i am doing this way , its storing the whole date and numeric

```
var dateData[]

for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++)  
{
 dateData.push(i);
}
```

I am using only prototype.js and pure javascript .
Please help . Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dateData = [];
var priceData = [];

for( var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++ ){
  dateData.push( data.items[i][0] );
  priceData.push( data.items[i][1] );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , using dateData.push( data.items[i][0] ); is storing only dates , and also i want to push the numeric data in another array for example pricedata.push( data.items[i][1] ); is not working

Answer (score 3):

Another functional way to write the same,

```
var dateData = data.items.map(function(item) {
    return item[0];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateData = [];

data =  {"items":[["Jan 1, 2010",1],["Jan 2, 2010",2]]};

for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++)
{
 dateData.push(data.items[i][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No prototype.js required, just pure JS here:

```
var obj = {"items":[["Jan 1, 2010",1],["Jan 2, 2010",2]]};
var dateData = [];
for (var i in obj.items) {
    if (obj.items.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        dateData.push(obj.items[i][0]);
    }
}
```